# Why is my sass class name not showing up in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm in the middle of converting my website into react which includes having to convert my npm node-sass to npm sass.

Intro.js

```
import styles from "./intro.scss"

<section id='intro'>
   <div className={`myclass ${styles.intro}`}>Comes out undefined</div> 
   <div className={styles.intro}>Is empty</div>
   <div className="intro">This works</div>
</section>
```

intro.scss is in the same folder

```
.intro {
  color: red;
}
```

I'm trying to do it the supposed "correct way" as shown in tutorials but WTF? The class name only shows up in the module if I keep it static.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems "module" is required in the file name. The way everyone else talks about it sounded like a personal naming convention than an important factor to making it work.